# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory appends compressed folder with a double extension

Tags: c#, winforms, io, compression

I'm considering the possibility of this being a bug. My method creates a zip file, and appears to write files and folders to it correctly. As soon as I pass the catch block, it hits a FileNotFound exception, and on inspection of the .zip, it has appended the file in the following format:
`[filename].zip.zip`

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
private void compressDirectory()
{
    zipPath = backupPath + @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm") + ".zip";
//At this point, zipPath has the value "c:\testfacility\tree\<date+time>" 
                                                   //which definitively exists.
    try
    {
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcePath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
        getresultmessage(); //this line is never hit
    }
    catch (IOException v)
    {
        errMsg = "Failed trying to start compression. \n" + v.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you putting your output zip file into the same folder you are trying to zip?

Comment: Since the `FileNotFoundException` is not an exception that can be thrown by the `CreateFromDirectory` method, I'd recommend looking around to see if you are not having some kind of race condition that delete files during the zipping process


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What does `Directory.Exists(sourcePath)` return? I'd wager `false`.

Comment: @spender `P:\Backups\Test` which is a mapped network drive. I can navigate there in explorer, and it is definitely mapped to P:\

Comment: @Wolfish ...but what does `Directory.Exists(sourcePath)` actually say? Is that path mapped for the user under which your process is running?

Comment: @spender Pardon me, I made a mistake. sourcePath returns the correct source path, which the user (myself) has the correct permissions to access. The app itself is also running under my username. For clarification, it returns `C:\[foldername]\[sourcedirectory]`